# Convert the Time into UK time in java

Tags: java

I am working on requirment for my client.Please suggest me here.

I want to convert a given time into UK time.
For example ,If i give 10:00 AM IST to the function,then it should return me the Equivalent time of 10:00 AM IST in UK time.

Please tell me how can i handle the Daylight System in java code.

Thank you very Much in Advance ,Alisha

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: The UK has more than one [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_Kingdom#IANA_time_zone_database). Are you looking for GMT *or* "Europe/London"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I suspect it's *far* more likely that the OP is looking for Europe/London. Indeed, from the page you linked to: "The IANA time zone database contains one zone for the United Kingdom in the file zone.tab, named Europe/London."

Comment: Our Server in UK.Now in GMT+1 is running.I want to built a code which will handle DST ,it will give me the correct time

Comment: Then look at the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
long time= //yourTime
return now + london.getOffset(time);
```

Comment: When the DST will be started ,Do i need to change the  "TimeZone london = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");",Some different timezone id to it.

Comment: @alakhya: Well firstly - have you tested to see whether or not it works? But basically, it should be fine. The Europe/London time zone should reflect the local time in London at the specified point in time, whether that's observing DST or not.